# Why Cygwin has old Clang (v8)?

Tags: clang, cygwin

Are there any special reasons why Cygwin Clang is so outdated (see [here](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/clang.html)), version 8, while already version 13 exists?

For example Ubuntu (apt), MSYS2, MSVC all have version 12.

Also does anyone know (any links?) if there is any very simple way (like docker-based) to build recent Clang for Cygwin? Maybe Clang has no support for Cygwin anymore, that's why Cygwin has outdated version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/clang.html

The reason is very simple, there is no current maintainer.
The previous one has no more available time to dedicate to the project.

Comment: So strange that such important and popular program has no maintainer.

Comment: The volunteer maintainers are few and that maintainer was taking care of a lot of the load. https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin-apps/2020-March/039878.html . A portion of the load has been redistributed but additional volunteers are always welcome https://cygwin.com/packaging-contributors-guide.html